# Where do I purchase Microsoft Enterprise Agreement?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, microsoft-teams, microsoft

Where can I able to purchase the Microsoft Enterprise Agreement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare all Microsoft 365 Enterprise plans and buy them using below Microsoft official reference:

[Compare all Microsoft 365 Enterprise plans](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/compare-office-365-plans)

Check additional resources related to Enterprise Agreement at:

1. [Enterprise Agreement | Microsoft Volume Licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/licensing-programs/enterprise?)
2. [Create an Enterprise Agreement subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/create-enterprise-subscription)

Comment: Thanks dood. But my actual question is how to enroll for Enterprise agreement and where to buy the subscription(Volume Licenses) ?

Comment: check updated answer